# Find the differences between two maps

Tags: java, guava

I have two maps current and previous and I want to see if there is any difference between the 2 maps. If either a new key is present in the currentMap or if the values are different for the same key I can stop.

```
Map<String, String> previousValue;
Map<String, String> currValue;

boolean isChangePresent = currValue.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(
                    x -> !previousValue.containsKey(x.getKey()) ||
                        (previousValue.get(x.getKey()) != null && !previousValue.get(x.getKey()).equals(
                            x.getValue())));
```

Is there a better way to do this or a built-in utility function which does something of this sort?

Comment: What's wrong with `previousValue.equals(currValue)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner it doesn't do what the OP seems to be asking: i.e. check that all entries from currValue are contained in previousValue. i.e. `previousValue.entrySet().containsAll(currValue.entrySet())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Guava:

```
MapDifference<String, String> mapDifference = Maps.difference(currValue, previousValue);

return !mapDifference.entriesOnlyOnLeft().isEmpty() 
        || !mapDifference.entriesDiffering().isEmpty();
```

https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/guava-map-difference-example/

Answer (score 3):

Since your key and value are just `Strings`, their `.equals()` method checks for logical equality (rather than checking if they have the same memory address), so you can simply use

```
boolean check(Map<String, String> a, Map<String, String> b) {
     return a.equals(b);
}
```

Just be careful because if you have, for example, two maps of type `Map<K,V>` where `V` does not have overridden `.equals()` method, and the default equals method of `V` does not check for logical equality, then it will not work.

**Edit:**

Looking at your wording more carefully, do you consider a change to be present if the `keySet` of `previousMap` contains all of the keys of `currentMap` **but** `currentMap` has fewer keys than `previousMap`? If you consider there to be *no change* then what you need to do is

```
boolean check(Map<String, String> previous, Map<String, String> current) {
         Map<String,String> copyOfPrev = new HashMap<>();
         previous.forEach((k,v) -> copyOfPrev.put(k,v));
         copyofPrev.keySet().retainAll(current.keySet());
         return copyOfPrev.equals(current);
    }
```

keeping in mind that `Map<K, V>#keySet().retainAll(Collection<K> c)` modifies the underlying map, so the deep copy is to prevent changes to the previous map. If you're okay with changing the previous map, then you can just erase the first three lines of the body of that method, and change `copyOfPrev` to `previous`.

Comment: Why not simply use `previousValue.entrySet().containsAll(currValue.entrySet())`?

Comment: @JBNizet yes, that is a better way, I didn't realize you were putting entrySet. My suggestion is a more manual way of doing what you've suggested. Although something tells me OP really just intends to check if the maps are dead on equal, but the wording suggest what you've mentioned here.